# Is there a way to have clipboard buffering in OS X?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

Does OS X have this built in?  It is tedious with only one buffer.

Comment: An application like Clips or Jump Cut can help manage multiple things in your clipboard.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend something like [Jumpcut](http://jumpcut.sourceforge.net/):

> Jumpcut is an application that provides "clipboard buffering" — that is, access to text that you've cut or copied, even if you've subsequently cut or copied something else. The goal of Jumpcut's interface is to provide quick, natural, intuitive access to your clipboard's history.

[image]

[Flycut](https://github.com/TermiT/Flycut) is another option.

> Description: Flycut is a clean and simple clipboard manager for developers. It based on open source app called Jumpcut.

[image]

Comment: Can't believe no-one voted for this until me just now, what a great screenshot for Jumpcut :)

Comment: @stuffe I was wondering the same thing! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Control K (to cut)and Y (to paste) can be used for this functionality i believe. although it's more or a cut and paste rather than copy.

Comment: Those are the Emacs keybindings. Neat. I knew about C-a and C-e. But I did not know Cocoa supported kill and yank as well! Thanks for the hint! :)

Answer (score 3):

[Launchbar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) offers clipboard history among a gazillion other features. I recommend Launchbar because once you get used to it, you can rarely use your mac without it :)

Particularly:

> Clipboard History
>
> Seamless integration in LaunchBar’s standard interface. Unique
>   features such as stack operation (last-in/first-out), ClipMerge™, etc.
>   Paste as Plain Text option. Paste a sequence of clipboard objects
>   using Paste and remove from history. Quick Look integration. Clipboard
>   objects can be used for LaunchBar actions such as browsing, send-to,
>   drag & drop, etc. Customizable Ignore List to protect sensitive data.

But there are other "multiple clipboard" utilities for Mac and you can surely find a lot by just googling. [iClip](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/iclip/) is a popular one.

Answer (score 1):

I use the clipboard history in [Alfred](http://alfredapp.com). You need to buy the Powerpack to use it and it only supports plain text, but it's searchable, I like the UI, and you can set it to keep all history for up to three months.

[image]